# Overloading operator<< for a private enum

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

My class has a private `enum` whose members are being used to index an array of strings, the output of which is written to an output stream.

```
private:
    enum supportedMessageTypes(CRITICAL = 0, WARNING, INFORMATION);
    string messages[3];

//meanwhile, inside the constructor,
messages[3] = {"Critical error message", 
               "Warning message", 
               "Information message"};
```

Since I'm going to be using the enum values around my code a lot, I'd like to be able to overload `operator<<` to perform a lookup of the enum value, match it to the corresponding string in the array, and return that in the following manner:

```
cout << CRITICAL << ": " << messageText << std::endl;
```

The problem I have is that `supportedMessageTypes` is private while overloading of `operator<<` should be done as a non-member function. I know I can define a `friend` function that overloads `operator<<` for my class, but I'm simply not comfortable with breaking encapsulation in that way, and was wondering if anyone knew of a way to overload `operator<<` without using `friend` functions or making `supportedMessageTypes` public?

Comment: In this scenario it is perfectly fine to befriend the operator. This is one of the intended use-cases. See [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html#faq-14.2) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: If used correctly, friend enhances encapsulation. Here, friend is appropriate. See, http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html#faq-14.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible. You want to accept an argument of type `supportedMessageTypes`, so it must be visible. There's no way around it.

Also, a `friend` function wouldn't be bad here; this is one of the intented scenarios for friendship.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot agree with some of the premises in your question. In particular, when you say that declaring the `operator<<` as a `friend` function breaks encapsulation. It breaks encapsulation in exactly the same way as any member function of your type breaks encapsulation. The `operator<<` *is part* of your type and has access to the `private` parts, but that is not a breakage of encapsulation. Note that in C++ not only member functions belong to the interface of the type. Google for *interface principle*.

```
class test {
   enum E { ok, nok };
   friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, E );
};
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, E e ) {
   if ( e == ok ) out << "ok";
   else out << "nok";
   return out;
}
```

Note that you are not opening your class to *anyone*, only to one of *your* functions. If you feel at unease, think of this almost equivalent way of generating the same code:

```
class test {
    enum E { ok, nok }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, E e ) {
       if ( e == ok ) out << "ok";
       else out << "nok";
       return out;
    }
};
```

How is that code *less encapsulated* than your original code?

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/gMTZ6

Dispite my efforts, I couldn't find a way to do this without the `friend` keyword.  On the other hand, this does *not* break encapsulation, as nobody outside of your class can *use* the function, since they cannot access the type being used in the type lookup.  Ergo, you're still fully encapsulated.